# Rails: Convert has_many to has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Assuming I have an existing app with the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locations, :through => :location_users
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :through => :location_users
end
```

How do I go about converting this has_many to a has_one association like below, as far as migrations, trimming records of people with multiple locations, and anything else I missed? Are there any shortcuts to do this conversion?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

EDIT: User belongs to one and only one location

Comment: Are you sure you want to have the `locations` table store the primary key of `user_id`? Or should it be that the `users` table stores a single `location_id` (i.e. a user will belong to one and only one location)?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to have User belong_to :location and Location has_many :users? ... Yeah, what carlosramireziii said.

Comment: y'all correct, that's a typo in my logic. I'll edit it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Shortcuts.

Write a migration to add `location_id` to `users` table

```
class AddLocationIdToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :location_id, :integer
  end
end
```

And you can write another migration to populate the location_id for the existing users.
For eg, if you want to populate the first location_id for the user in the locations_users table

```
class PopulateLocationIdOnUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    #executing direct query to speed up the operation
    execute("update users set location_id = (select location_id from locations_users where locations_users.user_id = users.id limit 1)")
  end

  def down
    execute("update users set location_id = null")
  end
end
```

And another migration to drop locations_users table

```
class DropLocationsUsersTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    drop_table :locations_users
  end

  def down
    create_table :locations_users do |t|
     #columns
    end
  end
end
```

You can also have a single migration to do all the three steps too.

Comment: Sorry, could you please revise your answer? I just made an edit where User belongs to one and only one location

Comment: @ChaseT.: Modified the answer

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that the last migration is irreversible. Might want to add `raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration, "Can't recover the deleted data"` at the end of the down method of DropLocationsUsersTable migration.

Comment: You can't reverse the data. But you can still create the schema so your code doesn't throw up when you revert back to a older version

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really an easy way around this. You're going to have to do a lot of manually work from my experience. This is how I went about it:

1. Write a migration to add `user_id` to the locations table.
2. Run the migration
3. Add the has_one relation code. (like you have above)

   ```
   class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_one :location
   end

   class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
   end
   ```
4. Either write a migrations to convert all the existing data over. (e.g. `location.user = location.users.first`). But it might be better in this case to write a rake task because this will only happen once and it will need to relay on your `has_many` relationship code to exist. So your migration would be invalid once you remove the `has_many` code.
5. Run your rake task
6. Remove the `has_many` code and join table.

After doing all that it should all work. Others might have a better way but this is how I did it.